# Validate Apple Access Token against email address and user id during apple sign in

Tags: node.js, flutter, apple-sign-in

I authenticated a user via firebase login using the Apple Sign in option on flutter.

Now, I have gotten the user's email and name successfully together with the accessToken.

Now, is there a way to validate the accessToken against the email and name?

For google I could easily do the following in my backend to validate the access token:

```
axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=${accessToken}`).then(async (response) => {
            //And validate the response against the user email and id
        });
```

Is there something similar for apple?